# Getting TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

Tags: puppeteer

I don't know why my browser is giving me timeout, it's kind of slow because I'm using proxies but I have set on the launch options that the timeout should be 0

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ['--proxy-server=http://ip:port'],
        timeout: 0
      });
```

Anyone knows how can i fix this? thanks

I expected the browser not to crash (close) after 30000 ms , but it's giving me timeout

Comment: I don't see that timeout property in the docs: https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.puppeteerlaunchoptions. You probably meant to call `page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)` or `page.goto(url, {timeout: 0})`. But 0 is infinite--probably not a good idea. I suggest setting that to no more than 5 or 10 minutes. If a navigation is ever taking that long, it's probably a bug you should know about. I'd throw and either log and exit or log and restart.